# Why does my dynamic disk say it is not formatted after a power loss?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, dynamic-disk

I have a Windows Dynamic disk of three 3 Terabyte drives in a single spanned volume. Today I experienced a power loss and didn't get to turn my computer off before my UPS died (I guess I shouldn't be so cheap). When I try to access the drive, I receive the error:

[image]

I thought that the partition might have been damaged somehow, so I downloaded PartitionGuru to check it. However, the partition seems to show up:

[image]

I am by no means an expert user of the program, but it seems as if the partitions are in store. However, I suppose it's possible they were corrupted? In any event, I'm not sure what I should do. They are three separate drives and the drive as a whole shows up in Disk Management as healthy, but unformatted?

Comment: can you format the drive? or are you trying to avoid doing that, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. is the drive corrupted? we won't know until you tell us what you have tried to get it back to normal

Comment: Ya, I'm trying to save the data on the drive. I could format if I wanted to.

Comment: so what exactly are you asking us to help you with? are you asking us to predict what happened with your drive after your power outage?

Comment: I'd like to think it's pretty clear I'm trying to recover the volume?

Comment: no where in your question does it say "how do I recover the volume?" how is that obvious to anyone.